# ", he/she on ..." vs. ", him/her on ..."

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Example sentence:

> They sat across from each other, **he/him** on the chair, **she/her**
> on the bed.

Should it be he/she or him/her? And why?

Comment: He sat on the chair. She sat on the bed. Both are subjects, not objects.

Comment: People who are into Latin grammar will doubtless agree with @Kate above. But I don't have any problem with the usage *...him on the left and her on the right* in such contexts. Maybe it's the same as *[She's a] **friend of his / friend of him***, I dunno. I suggest only a small minority of native speakers know or care whether they should use "nominative" or "accusative" case for pronouns in such contexts. But it's not obvious to me how ***He sat** on the chair* "explains" anything - why not "rephrase / expand" as ***with him sitting** on the chair*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers While I (theoretically) believe that there is no "right" or "wrong" in language, and that nobody appreciates a hardliner... Maybe it's just me, but I'd argue that using him/her in the example sentence would still *sound* wrong. And, yes, if we want to get formal, it would break grammatical validity, because the two pronouns "divide up" *they* and are subjects, but I don't think it's one of those "meh, it might be wrong but everybody says it" situations.

Comment: @AndyBonner: If it "sounds wrong" to you, i can't argue! But it *doesn't* sound wrong to me. I don't know why, but when I search for a sequence like **him standing her sitting** (or **he standing she sitting**) I get several pages of results in Google Books, but few or none where I can actually read the sought text *in context*. Neverthless, I'm quite certain both forms are reasonably common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oddly enough, if I imagine versions with "I" and "you," I'm more receptive to "me" ("you" of course is still "you"). It's good enough for Stephen Sondheim: "Isn't it rich / are we a pair / me here at last on the ground / you in midair" ("Send in the Clowns," from *A Little Night Music*)

Comment: I changed the title because both versions in the original were the same.  If I changed the meaning of your question, my apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pronouns as subject of a verb (basically, "someone does something to anything"):

```
 He/She sits on a chair. I/You/They sit on a chair.
```

Pronouns as object of a verb (basically, "something happens to someone"):

```
 The chair belongs to him/her/me/them.
```

It might sound OK to use the wrong pronoun form, but not really, because in the back of my mind, an object pronoun reverses the receiver of the action, so it sounds like this:

*They sat across from each other, the chair holding him, the bed supporting her.*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But sorry, so you're saying that the *he/she* or *him/her* version is the correct one?

Comment: For the sentence in the question, use "he" and "she" sat on the chairs. 
You would only use "him" and "her" if the chairs sat on *them* (which would be very strange).

Answer (score 2):

You might be able use either "he" or "him", but to my ears "him" is better.

This is because of the lack of an explicit verb in these phrases.  Without a verb there is no unambiguous subject, and so the pronouns default to their object forms.

I don't accept an argument that says *it* should *be "he" because "he on the bed" is really short for "he sat on the bed"*.  It could be understood like this, but the phrase "he/him on the bed" really doesn't have a verb.  It could equally be understood as "There was him on the bed".

No verb -> no subject -> use him.

Comment: Sorry, but 1) if there were in fact no verb, then one could argue that there should be no *object*, and 2) yeah, there's a verb. I'm not sure, tbh, whether it's more accurate to argue that *sat* "projects" itself into the later phrases, or to say that the phrases "restate" the initial one, and simply "divide up" the pronoun *they*, but either way, nobody's getting sat *upon* but the chair. Like our last encounter, the question of whether one would prefer to be right or idiomatic is separate (see my confusion in the comments), but there's definitely a "proper" way.

Comment: And yet, to my judgement,  "he on the chair" simply sounds wrong.  So whatever the "rule" is, it had better say that "him" is the correct pronoun in this case.

Comment: I think it could also be understood as "with him on the bed"?

Answer (score 0):

> They sat across from each other, he/him on the chair, she/her on the bed.

To resolve the absence of verbs in the two phases, we could consider ellipsis.

> They sat across from each other; he, on the chair; she, on the bed.

The gapping commas indicate the verb omissions.